# User Sub with Optional parameters - not visible in Macro window

Tags: vba, excel, udf

I have a macro that goes through column(s) and removed numbers from all cells in the range.  I would like to add an optional parameter, so I can call the sub while telling it which columns to run on.  Here's what I have:

`Sub GEN_USE_Remove_Numbers_from_Columns(Optional myColumns as String)`

The idea being I can call it from another sub, like this `GEN_USE_...Columns("A B C")`

But, I can't run that from the VB Editor, nor can I see that macro in the Macro Window (when clicking View --> Macros).  Why not? Why do I *have* to call it with a parameter (even `GEN_USE_...Columns("")`) I can't just call `GEN_USE_...Columns()` anymore.

I've [seen that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f25e2b6b.aspx) you can add `= Nothing` to the end, to set a default value if none is given.  I've tried that () but it didn't do anything.

I guess my question is A) How come I can't see my macros that have Optional parameters, in the macro window? and B) Why can't I call the macro with parameters directly from the VB Editor? I have to actually create a sub, then I can call the macro within that sub.  No more just highlighting some text and hitting "Play".

I know the two issues are probably related, so any insight would be appreciated!

(PS: I know we're supposed to post code, but I don't think that's very relevant. Of course, if you'd like to see it, let me know and I'll update).

Comment: Use `Optional myColumns as Variant` to show it in the Run Macro ([alt]+[F8]) dialog. Alternately, leave it hidden; you can type the name and click Run. The variant type is also teh only one that responds properly to `IsMissing`.

Comment: You can call the sub with parameters from the VBE's Immediate window ([ctrl]+G).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `Optional myColumns as Variant` to show it in the Run Macro ([alt]+[F8]) dialog. Alternately, leave it hidden; you can type the name and click Run. The variant type is also the only one that responds properly to the [IsMissing function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445048%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

```
Sub GEN_USE_Remove_Numbers_from_Columns(Optional myColumns As Variant)
    If IsMissing(myColumns) Then
        myColumns = Intersect(Selection.Parent.UsedRange, Selection).Address '.address 'cause you were using a string
    End If
    Debug.Print Range(myColumns).Address(external:=True)
End Sub
```

[image: optional_ismissing]

You can call the sub with parameters from the VBE's Immediate window ([ctrl]+G).

Comment: Aha! That's a pretty neat "trick".  I like this because I use `F8` a ton to walkthrough and this allows me to use the macro like a "normal" one, without really much more complication.  Tangent, but I noticed that if I run the sub without giving any `myColumns` data, using `If IsEmpty(myColumns)` will return `FALSE`...despite `myColumns` having `Nothing`.  (Then I noticed it's actually `IsMissing`, so switched it. Just a counterintuative quirk I think with `IsEmpty`).

Comment: Yes, testing the existence of an optional parameter against `Is Nothing` or with the [IsEmpty function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264227.aspx) does not produce correct results. A variant type parameter with the [IsMissing function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445048%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) is the best test. Alternately, hardcode impossible values (constants) as defaults and test if the parameter equals those constants.

Answer (score 7):

A Sub with ANY parameters, optional or not, cannot be run directly and can only be called from another Sub or Function

Best option is to write a wrapper Sub that will appear in the Macros window

```
Sub USER_Remove_Numbers_from_Columns()
    GEN_USE_Remove_Numbers_from_Columns
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this one! I'll keep this in mind for macros in the future. For this specific one, Jeeped's answer works a little better, but thanks a lot for your answer and comment!!